# GNU makefile shell command not working properly

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have these 2 lines

```
GCC_VERSION=$(shell gcc --version | grep 'gcc (GCC)' | awk '{print $3}')

$(info $$GCC_VERSION is [${GCC_VERSION}])
```

It prints out:

```
$GCC_VERSION is [gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
```

instead of the expected 4.8.5.

Any reason why it's not work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need `$(shell gcc --version 2>&1 ...)`. We have to do some version checking too. Also see [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile).

Comment: Tried both gcc --version 2>&1 ... and gcc --version 2>/dev/null ...  Still same result.

Comment: @jww, I'm afraid you are wrong.  `gcc --version` already outputs the version string on stdout, or then, `grep(1)` should not pass it to `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `awk` command into

```
awk '{print $$3}'
```

otherwise `make` will not invoke `awk '{print $3}'` but `awk '{print }'`, as the make variable `$3` is expanded to an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. Stumbled upon this fact while waiting and searching on the internet in the same time.

Comment: Also notice how most occurrences of `grep 'x' | awk 'y'` are a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which should be refactored to `awk '/x/ y'`